# Is it possible to hack database server that open only 3 ports?

Tags: database, security

From [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969539/whats-the-best-way-to-keep-decryption-key-for-decrypting-encrypted-database), I have new idea for database protection. The following ports will be connected via SSL only. Is it possible to hack this database server?

1. **Http Port** for sending & receiving data via WCF Services or Web Services.
2. **Ftp Port** for updating above services.

PS. This question is not include SQL injection problem.

**Thanks,**

Comment: One for ServerFault, I think.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: It can be on both.

Comment: "Hey this is <name> over here in <department> I need the SQL server password so I can run some diagnostics..."

Comment: Which is the better way to secure my database between encryption database or using middle tier for accessing database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to hack just about anything. Your HTTP or (especially) your FTP server could have security bugs in it which open a backdoor. These could be anything from arbitrary code execution under `root`/`Administrator` or full filesystem access.

I assume also that your database server is also not bug-free, and could expose all your data.

Obviously, though, having as few ports as possible open is better.

Comment: FTP server & web server bug may not leak my data in database Because i run Ftp server process with normal user account and It isn't same as database drive. So, hacker can't access to database files. Moreover, database files is still locked by DBMS. Right?

Comment: With code execution (very reasonably) providing shell access (see http://metasploit.org), the attacker could kill the DBMS. Or copy the files out. Again, this allows access to DB drive through FTP/HTTP vulnerability. A normal user account is possibly insufficient - you may need an even more restricted account. Those still are sensible precautions, though. You may want to add them to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, you can never make your server hacker-proof.  As long as hackers have some means to send data to the server, they can potentially exploit security vulnerabilities to do bad things.  Limiting the server's surface area, using encryption, and so on all help and make it less *likely* you'll get hacked, but you're never 100% safe.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, but sure this decrease the possibilities.

Comment: Which is the better way to secure my database between encryption database or using middle tier for accessing database.

Answer (score 0):

you can still guess/predict/keylog the username/password and get in

Answer (score 0):

I always tell people the only hack-proof server is the one that is unplugged and powered down in the closet.

It is important, when presenting a security solution, do identify what kind of intrusion you are attempting to guard against.  Even with only three ports open, even with one for that matter, a successful dictionary attack against accounts accessing the server via FTP port could do some damage.

As a general rule, we do not expose our databases directly outside the network/firewall.  Only web or user application servers have exposed ports but nothing that isn't behind the firewall can directly touch the database servers.

Answer (score 0):

This is still vulnerable several ways:

1. Man in the middle attack against SSL if you don't have proper certs set up
2. Input handling exploits in your httpd, ftpd and operating system
3. Social engineering

That doesn't mean it's not a good idea to do things this way, but it's dangerous to think this, or anything really, is "hack proof". I'll spare you the typical wisecrack about windows security.